# Аналог Nunit атрибута TestCase в MSTest

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, nunit, mstest

Подскажите какой атрибут в **MSTest** является аналогом атрибута `[TestCase]` в фреймворке **NUnit**?

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest

Comment: Странно я ее просматривал но не увидел, теперь увидел спасибо) вот ссылка на раздел https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest#adding-more-features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Атрибут `[DataTestMethod]` представляет набор тестов, которые выполняют один и тот же код, но имеют разные входные аргументы. С помощью атрибута `[DataRow]` можно указать значения для этих входных аргументов.

```
[DataTestMethod]
[DataRow(-1)]
[DataRow(0)]
[DataRow(1)]
public void ReturnFalseGivenValuesLessThan2(int value)
{
    var result = _primeService.IsPrime(value);

    Assert.IsFalse(result, $"{value} should not be prime");
}
```